# Why \underbrace and \overbrace create brackets with gaps?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath

I noticed that when we use `\underbrace` and `\overbrace`, it creates a bracket that is assembled by several parts, please see the picture below demonstrating what I mean:
[image]

If we zoom in, we can see:
[image]

And[image]

Which causes a small inconsistency, and I am puzzled because this is not a glitch, it's how the package made it to be, I just wonder if there's any reason why they make it this way?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\underbrace{\left(A_{N} \cdot \int_{\left(m_{-i}, v\right)} \frac{v}
{\operatorname{rank}\left(m_{i} ; m\right)} \rho\left(d m_{-i}, d v | 
m_{i}\right)-X_{N}, t_{i}(1)\right)}_{ \leq A_{N} \cdot 
t_{i}^{\prime}\left(m_{i}\right)-X_{N}=t_{i}\left(m_{i}\right) \text { if } m_{i}<1}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, make a complete example, in particular it's needed to know the font package you're using.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for reminding me, I've added a minimal code, the only package I use is `amsmath`

Comment: [This is the picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ66g.png) I get, which is quite different from yours. The font is different.

Comment: @egreg Yes, the picture is from a journal article and the code is reproduced, but this doesn't affect my question because the gaps are even more obvious in your picture.

Comment: What you see in the picture is not “the real thing”, because of rasterization at small resolution; I was just pointing out that the font is not the same. [Here (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHEol.png) is the central part at high resolution. The journal is using a different font and *that* makes the difference. The PDF viewer and your screen can have a role.

Comment: @TheR I agree with the comment of 100% egreg. You should enlarge the pdf and you don't see the collage. I only gave you an alternative answer of a bracket bracket that I like so much and is with a small tip.

Comment: @egreg you are right, and I think that is another problem that this "assembled" bracket causes, because there are 5 parts for each bracket, so sometimes it causes display inconsistency, from Sebastiano 's answer, I think the reason might be that a non-assembled bracket requires individual design according to its length, which may not be easily produceable in LaTeX right now.

Comment: you ask "why do they make it that way" but how else can you have an arbitrarily wide (or high) brackets?, all extendable characters in all fonts eventually result in multiple pieces being placed together. the alternative is to draw the brackets with something like tikz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My proposal is **only** an aesthetic alternative using, for example, `\undercbrace` from `lite mtpro2` package. I have reconsidered some changes of your original code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,mathtools}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[t_i(m_i)\geq \min\undercbrace{\left(A_N\cdot \int_{m_{-i},v} \frac{v}{\operatorname{rank}(m_{-i};m)}\rho(dm_{-i},dv\mid m_i)-X_Nm t_{i}(1)\right) }_{\leq A_{N} \cdot t'_{i}(m_{i})-X_{N}=t_{i}(m_{i}) \text { if } m_{i}<1}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, I can see in `mtpro2` the brackets are "individually designed" according to length so I suppose in `amsmath` package they didn't do so, so it retains the gap.

Comment: @TheR vertical and horizontal braces are the same, each font has a fixed number of glyphs then an extendable version made up of central and edge parts with repeatable straight extenders. Some fonts have a larger range of designed sizes before using the extenders but the basic principle is the same in any case.